# Column default is prioritized over insert value in INSERT..SELECT statement

Tags: sql, oracle11g

When inserting values into `TARGET_TABLE` with below `INSERT..SELECT` statement, the column default for the column `lastupdate` seems to be prioritized over the value resulting from the `SELECT` statement.

Even though there is always a value for this column in the `SOURCE_TABLE`.

Example:

`SOURCE_TABLE` contains `lastupdate = 16.08.12 15:41:44`

After executing the statement, `lastupdate` in `TARGET_TABLE` gets set to `SYSDATE`, e.g. `16.08.12 15:49:14`:

```
INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (A, B, C, D, LASTUPDATE, F)
        SELECT A, B, C, D, LASTUPDATE, F
            FROM SOURCE_TABLE
            WHERE B = 'some_value';


CREATE TABLE TARGET_TABLE
(
ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
A VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
B VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
C CLOB NOT NULL,
D VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
LASTUPDATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
E DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
)
```

Oracle version: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

I would like the value to be copied from `SOURCE_TABLE` to `TARGET_TABLE` and not to be set to `SYSDATE`.

What am I missing here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you copy and paste from a SQL*Plus session showing this behavior?  It doesn't reproduce on my 11.2 database and it's not something that I've ever personally seen happen.

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE TARGET_TABLE
  2  (
  3  ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  4  A VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  5  B VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  6  C CLOB NOT NULL,
  7  D VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  8  LASTUPDATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  9  E DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
 10  );

Table created.

SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  CREATE TABLE SOURCE_TABLE
  2  (
  3  ID NUMBER NOT NULL,
  4  A VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  5  B VARCHAR2(255 CHAR) NOT NULL,
  6  C CLOB NOT NULL,
  7  D VARCHAR2(255 CHAR),
  8  LASTUPDATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
  9  E DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE
 10* )
SQL> /

Table created.
```

I had to change your `INSERT` into `SOURCE_TABLE` to specify the column `E` rather than `F` since the `CREATE TABLE` statement only had a column `E`.

```
SQL> insert into source_table( id, a, b, c,d, lastupdate, e )
  2    values( 1, 'A', 'some_value', empty_clob(), 'D', date '2012-01-01', sysdate );

1 row created.
```

I also had to change your `INSERT` into `TARGET_TABLE` to add the `ID` column since that has a `NOT NULL` constraint.  I'm assuming that in your actual example this is probably getting populated by a trigger on `TARGET_TABLE` that is selecting the data from a sequence.  Is it possible that this trigger (or some other trigger) is setting the `LASTUPDATE` value as well?

```
SQL> ed
Wrote file afiedt.buf

  1  INSERT INTO TARGET_TABLE (ID, A, B, C, D, LASTUPDATE, E)
  2          SELECT ID, A, B, C, D, LASTUPDATE, E
  3              FROM SOURCE_TABLE
  4*             WHERE B = 'some_value'
SQL> /

1 row created.

SQL> select id, lastupdate from target_table;

        ID LASTUPDAT
---------- ---------
         1 01-JAN-12
```

Comment: Thx for the hint regarding the trigger, you are absolutely right. I was so sure it would only generate the ID (as you've written correctly), but this thing also updates the lastupdate column. And sry about the mismatch regarding E/F. Due to missing permissions on the DB i was not able to see the trigger definition in the first place. Thx a lot.